# Create Custom Enum Type

Tags: sapui5

I want to create a custom enum type for the custom control like https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.ValueState.html#.Error.

My questions are:

- How can I create an enum type?
- On the custom control, you will be able only to pass property enum
  type. How can I validate if the given enum is valid or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example: [https://embed.plnkr.co/DhtkXOkMi12D1AYK](https://embed.plnkr.co/DhtkXOkMi12D1AYK?show=custom/control/type/MyColor.js,preview)

In order to create an enum type in UI5, there are **certain rules to take into account:**

- The enum definition **must be a plain object**. Internally, it's validated via [`sap/base/util/isPlainObject`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/base/util/isPlainObject.js).
- Each **key-value pair must be identical** to each other.
- Renaming is not supported.
- Only keys and values of type *string* are
  supported.

```js
{
  "Red": "Red",
  "Blue": "Blue",
  "Yellow": "Yellow"
}
```

In order to actually make use of the enum object:

1. The enum object **must be registered with [`sap/ui/base/DataType.registerEnum`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.base.DataType%23methods/sap.ui.base.DataType.registerEnum)*** since UI5 1.120. For example:

   ```js
   /**
   * In control/type/Color.js"
   * Root namespace: "my.demo"
   */
   sap.ui.define([
     "sap/ui/base/DataType",
   ], (DataType) => {
     "use strict";
     const color = {
       Red: "Red",
       Blue: "Blue",
       Yellow: "Yellow",
     };
     DataType.registerEnum("my.demo.control.type.Color", color); // since 1.120
     return Object.freeze(color);
   }/*, true*//*no longer needed since UI5 1.120 thx to registerEnum*/);
   // Exporting globally (true) is required until 1.119.
   ```
2. The *module name* of the object must be assigned to the `type` in the property metadata:

   ```js
   // in control/Square.js
   sap.ui.define([
     "sap/ui/core/Control",
     "./type/Color", // require the module to register the enum
     "...",
   ], function(Control) {
     "use strict";

     return Control.extend("my.demo.control.Square", {
       metadata: {
         properties: {
           "selectedColor": {
             type: "my.demo.control.type.Color", // <-- name of the enum
             bindable: true,
           },
         },
       },
       // ...
     });
   });
   ```

In my example above, it's the `selectedColor` property that awaits only `"Red"`, `"Blue"`, or `"Yellow"`. Let's test it:

- `new Square().getMetadata().getProperty("selectedColor").getType().isEnumType()` returns `true`. ✔️
- `new Square().setSelectedColor("Hans")` throws an error as expected:

  > "Hans" is of type string, expected my.demo.control.type.Color for property "selectedColor" of Element [...]. ✔️
- `new Square().setSelectedColor("Yellow")` successfully stores the value. ✔️

---

### Note

Do **not** try creating an enum type via `DataType.create`.

> Array types and enumeration types cannot be created with this method. They're created *on-the-fly* by `DataType.getType` when such a type is looked up. [(Source)](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.base.DataType#methods/sap.ui.base.DataType.createType)

### References

- [DataType source code](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/base/DataType.js) (search for "enum" occurances)
- Documentation topic [Defining Control Properties](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/ac56d92162ed47ff858fdf1ce26c18c4)

---

* For UI5 1.119 or lower, refer to the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50223688/9).

Answer (score 0):

Start off by defining your enum...

**MessageType.js**

```
sap.ui.define([], function() {
    "use strict";

    return {
      Unread: "Unread",
      Read: "Read"
    };
});
```

Next, mark this enum as a dependency in your custom control so that you are able to validate the value.

**MyControl.js**

```
    sap.ui.define(["sap/ui/core/Control", "/path/to/MessageType.js"], function(Control, MessageType) {

        Control.extend("myControl", {
            someMethod: function(sMessageType) {
                // Validate if we are dealing with a valid message type
                var aKeys = Object.keys(MessageType);
                var bValidEnumValue = aKeys.some(function(sKey) {
                    if (MessageType[sKey]) {
                        return true;
                    }
                });

                // Do other stuff..
            }
        });
    });
```

Of course the way to check if you are dealing with a valid enum value can be implemented in different ways depending on what you're trying to do.

```
if (sMessageType === MessageType.Read) {
   // do something
} else if (sMessageType === MessageType.Unread) {
   // do something else 
} else {
   // throw an error?
}
```